# Interpretation of Individual Effects with Inlcusion of Year Dummies in Fixed Effects Regression for Unbalanced Panels

Tags: r, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, plm

I work on my research in finance and I am running an **unbalanced panel fixed effects regression**. My dataset consists of 101 units (bonds) for which I have daily observations of their ask yield since the bond's issuance date (the earliest observation comes from January 29, 2014) until January 30, 2020. Therefore, the panel is unbalanced with T ranging from 81 to 1,415 days according to the issuance date of the respective bond.

I run a fixed-effects within regression:

```
model_fe = plm(yield_diff ~ Bid_ask, data  = mydata.set, model = "within")
```

and I am particularly interested in the individual effects captured by the intercepts:

```
fixef(model_fe)
summary(fixef(model_fe))
```

**Now the problematic part comes:**
I want to see if the dependent variable varies in time and thus I add year dummies for all year except for 2014 which is my base year:

```
model_TE = plm(yield_diff ~ Bid_ask + factor(year), data  = mydata.set, model = "within")
```

4 out of the 6 year dummies are statistically significant, therefore, it makes sense to include them in the regression. However, I am confused how to interpret the individual effects now. I have two questions:

1. I again obtain the individual fixed effects by

```
fixef(model_TE)
summary(fixef(model_TE))
```

Logically, I would assume that now the intercept for let's say individual i=1 captures the individual effect for this particular bond in the base year (i.e. 2014). To get the individual effect for i=1 in 2015, I just sum the intercept and the coefficient on 2015 year dummy etc. - Is this assumption correct?

2. The thing is that most bonds were issued after 2014. If my assumption in Question 1 is correct (i.e. the individual fixed effect retrieved by the fixef(model_TE) is the intercept for bond i = 1 in 2014) what does it mean for bonds that were not issued in this year, they were issued let's say in 2016?

Comment: Welcome! Do you want to add unit *and* time fixed effects? If so, you could get your time effects in other ways: `fixef(..., effect = “time”)`.

Comment: Tom, thanks for your answer. The thing is that I have daily data and deriving time effects like this gives me approximately 1,500 daily effects. So that is not what I am looking for. I want to see if the dependent variable changes across years thus adding the year dummies. The thing is that than I don't know how to interprete the individual effects (i.e. the intercepts for i=1, ..., 101) as now the intercept captures both the individual effect for i and the time effect for the base year?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. And when you say you have 101 “panels” do you mean you have separate panel datasets? Or, do you observe the units (i.e., bonds) across anywhere from 81 to 1,145 days?

Comment: Sorry, I will clarify this in my question - I have 101 units (bonds) and for each daily observations on price ranging from 81 to 1,145 days. The earliest observation comes from 2014 (in that year, I have only 2 bonds). As time passes, more bonds "are added" to the panel, i.e. in 2015 - 4 bonds, in 2016 - 14 bonds, in 2017 - 37 bonds, 2018 - 68 bonds, 2019 - 101 bonds, and  2020 - 101 bonds.

Comment: Something is wrong, you should not be able to estimate year effects, when you have day effects. For any year $g$ adding a year effect $\delta_g$ should be indistinguishable from adding this constant to all the day effects $\lambda_t$ for which the day is in the year $t \in g$, hence $\lambda_t' = \delta_g + \lambda_t$.

Comment: So for you to estimate year effects I think you would have to have some stock observed on the same day $t$ but being in different years $g$ and $g'$, whic h is logically impossible. If I were you I would look carefully at the coding of the time variable.